# How to make two arrays randomly equal each other

Tags: java, arrays, random, boolean, equals

The final piece of my project is to make two testing arrays, **grades[]** and **grades2[]** equal each other randomly to test my equals method statements. How do I use the java.util.Random correctly? Or if there is another method, I would love to hear it...

In this code, the program will forever output that the two objects are different (obviously) since the contents of the arrays are randomly generated. How do I make it to where they are randomly equal to each other?

```
public class GradeBookClient
{
   public static GradeBook classRoom1, classRoom2;
   public static void main( String [] args )
   {  
     //Create two new arrays for testing the equals() method
     int[] grades = new int[100];
     int[] grades2 = new int[100]; 

     for ( int i = 0; i <= grades.length-1; i++ )
     {
         grades[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
     }

     for ( int i = 0; i < grades2.length; i++ )
     {
         grades2[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
     }



      classRoom1 = new GradeBook (grades);
      System.out.println( "The class size is " + classRoom1.getStudent() + " students." + "\n" + classRoom1.toString() ); 


      classRoom2 = new GradeBook (grades2);
      System.out.println( "The class size is " + classRoom2.getStudent() + " students." + "\n" + classRoom2.toString() );

      if ( classRoom1.equals( classRoom2 ))
      System.out.println("Classroom 1 has the same grades and class size as Classroom 2.");
      else
      System.out.println("Classroom 1 and Classroom 2 have different grades and class sizes.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I got it right because it's not that clear, but maybe you should go with something like this:

```
//Create two new arrays for testing the equals() method
int[] grades = new int[100];
int[] grades2 = new int[100]; 

for ( int i = 0; i <= grades.length-1; i++ )
{
    int value = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    grades[i] = value;
    grades2[i] = value;
}
```

so that you can have two equal arrays filled with the same random values

Comment: I just give up, I will accept making them equal so it outputs that, I do not know what my teacher wants.

Answer (score 3):

This is an oxymoron. If it is random you can't make it equal to each other.

Edit: If you want to create two identical arrays which are randomly filled then you should fill an array with random numbers then copy it with `System.arraycopy()` or something like that.

Comment: I am fighting the logic with my teacher man. She said this in an email: "you are correct, using random data, it is very unlikely they will be the same.  You could create 2 identical arrays to test though"

Comment: Making one array then making a copy constitutes "creating 2 identical arrays".

Comment: Isn't copy a bit an overkill? He can build the two arrays within the same for, to avoid doing two loops for just one operation!

Comment: @StepTNT Same difference, really. One loop with two operations per step or two loops with one operation per step.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I make it to where they are randomly equal to each other?

You could first decide whether or not they should be equal. If they should be, just copy `grades` into `grades2` instead of generating `grades2` independently of `grades`.

Comment: I suggested that to her but then she told me that I should make two arrays identical to each other. What that means is beyond me but I think I am just not going to worry about it. Two classes in real life cannot have the same grades anyway, there's no logic to this assignment.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to make the contents of the two array equal:

- Put numbers in one array and copy to another
- else generate random number with same `seed`

`Random rand = new Random(seed);`

if your `seed` is equal then `rand.nextInt()` will generate same sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Create the first array using `Random`. Then, if you decide it should be equal to the second array, simply instantiate a new array of the same type and size and copy each position one by one.

Comment: That's not creating two identical arrays.